# pysimplegui ) keep position when I put Image

Tags: pysimplegui

I want to do this:

[image]

Without using `sg.frame.`. Is there any way to do this?

I'm sorry for my English.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use `sg.Column`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with columns as Jason mentioned in the comments.

```
first_column = [[sg.Image(key='-IMAGE-')]]
second_colum = [[sg.Text('First :')],
                [sg.Text('Second : ')],
                # ...
                ]

layout = [
    [sg.Column(first_column),
     sg.VSeperator(pad=(0, 0)),
     sg.Column(second_column),
     ]
]
```